# Microsoft Project and Waterfall

Tags: ms-project, waterfall

Microsoft Project and Waterfall

Does using Microsoft Project force you into a waterfall model? Could anyone point me to examples of successful iterative (agile for example) projects that successfully use(d) MS Project as a supporting tool?

Comment: A counter-question: does Microsoft Project help you run **any** project? The few times I've tried to use it, it was moderately helpful in visualizing the schedule and dependencies, but keeping it up to date over project changes (which inevitably occur) proved much too painful. Can anyone point out **waterfall** projects that succeeded using MS Project? (Or perhaps just waterfall projects that succeeded, come to think of it...!)

Comment: What always happens with grand MS project plans is that it's difficult to keep up with new tasks (at micro-level). And any task at high-level is always going to be fake updated by PMs to show % completion. If you're doing Agile, better off with XPlanner or FogBugz for the actual sprints, and the grand MS plan only shows the start/end dates of each Sprint

Comment: @abc: Why the redaction? Even a closed question can be useful to others. Even though it's your question, this is still vandalism.

Comment: I'm sick and tired of moderators closing my questions and deleting my comments. This used to be a fun place. Here's the question again, I'm restoring it since it seems to actually be USEFUL to someone. My apologies.

Comment: I actually think it's a great question. Unfortunately though, it is off-topic here. However instead of closing it, I wonder wy Bill didn't migrate it to Programmers?

Comment: That's what is even crazier - if I remember correctly THERE WAS NO Programmers at the time I asked the question. I still don't quite understand what the difference is between the two sites, and I don't really care. I used to display my real name, but not anymore. If they want to kick me out, that is fine with me as well I have better things to do.

Comment: I understand how you feel. There are several frustrating things about the way this site is run. But try not to let them get to you - it's not worth it. Take a deep breath and rise above it. Let it go, and move on to the next question. You're a good contributer.

Comment: Thank you, Charles. In the end I can't resist and I end up answering questions if I happen to know. Ah this is another issue I have - our comments here will very likely be deleted because they are considered more appropriate in the "chat" room, which I have to say I never visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider other alternatives for providing management with the transparency into development work which they presumably want. It's not going to help you with the frequent replanning that's at the core of agile methods -- MS Project is more likely to prove a hindrance.

Instead, talk to them about using low-tech whiteboards to show progress on objectives through e.g. percentages of user stories completed, estimated and actual velocities and highlighted issues. But if they're pushing MS Project, they're going to need to be at least tentatively converted to iterative/agile methods. [Google](http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2010/03/13/my-ten-development-principles/) [around](http://www.ataarticles.com/computers/a-brief-guide-explaining-how-agile-software-works/)... they may ask for figures to back your position: show them the numbers on agility rather than on MS Project.